# New HDD, wont load from USB or CD

Tags: usb

i have copied all of my re-installation disc(w7) to my USB. Computer won't read discs, does read the USB, but says there's no OS. This is a new HDD since my old one died. I need a step by step help as I am a noob and don't understand why this isn't working.

Comment: define "copied", more details please.

Comment: just dragged and dropped. I have tried to use the Rufus program to copy the ISO image, but there isn't one on the installation disc

Comment: it's the standard installation disc that came with my computer

Answer (score 1):

As @Keltari said, Rufus is able to be used to make your USB bootable with your Win 7 image, however you first need to capture an ISO image of the CD. For that, follow [this](http://www.poweriso.com/tutorials/iso-maker.htm) guide on capturing an ISO. Once you've captured your ISO, you can follow [this](http://www.techrepublic.com/article/pro-tip-use-rufus-to-create-a-bootable-usb-drive-to-install-almost-any-os/) guide, using your captured ISO in Rufus. Once that's finished, and if everything has completed successfully, your USB should now be a bootable Win 7 installer.

Comment: I haven't made myself clear. this is a BRAND NEW HDD WITH NOTHING LOADED on it. the HDD is completely blank. my computer is NOT reading  the installation disc. I have used another computer to try to put the installation disc on a USB thumbdrive.

Comment: I understand the HDD is empty, which is why I've answered you with instructions to installing Windows onto it. Your process for putting the installation disk onto a USB was incorrect, as the USB was not bootable because no links in the MBR were made to bootable sectors. Which is why you need to capture an ISO of the installation disk to use rufus to put it on the USB correctly.

Answer (score 0):

Copying will not work to make a bootable disk.  You need to do it in a special way.  [Rufus](https://rufus.akeo.ie/) is a program that will take your CD and make a bootable USB.

Comment: did you not understand that using rufus can't find the ISO from the installation disc?